# Bar graph spacing between grouped bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, grouped-bar-chart

I have a bar graph displaying annual counts of data from 1996-2020. Each year has 2 bars assigned to it. I can't figure out a way to increase the spacing between each group of 2 bars (or between each year). I know I can change the bar width, but that's not what I'm looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.set_style("ticks")


record_highs = pd.read_csv('MSY Audubon Record High Comparison 1996-2020.csv')

x= record_highs['Year']
aud = record_highs['AUD']
msy = record_highs['MSY']

plt.figure(figsize = (9,6))

plt.bar(x - 0.25, aud, width = 0.5)
plt.bar(x + 0.25, msy, width = 0.5)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1996, 2021, 1), rotation=45, fontsize=9)

plt.title('Record High Comparison \n May 1996-July 2020')
plt.ylabel('Number of Daily Record Highs by Year')
plt.legend(labels=['Audubon', 'MSY'])
plt.xlim([1995,2021])
```

[image: Record Highs Bar Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the center of the bars at `x - year_width/4` and `x + year_width/4`, e.g. choosing `year_width` to be `0.8`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.set_style("ticks")

x = np.arange(1996, 2021)
aud = np.random.randint(0, 26, len(x))
msy = np.random.randint(0, 26, len(x))

plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))

year_width = 0.8
plt.bar(x - year_width / 4, aud, width=year_width / 2, align='center')
plt.bar(x + year_width / 4, msy, width=year_width / 2, align='center')
plt.xticks(x, rotation=45, fontsize=9)

plt.title('Record High Comparison \n May 1996-July 2020')
plt.ylabel('Number of Daily Record Highs by Year')
plt.legend(labels=['Audubon', 'MSY'])
plt.xlim([1995, 2021])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]